# A question about unique factorization domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is example of a Euclidean domain so it both P.I.D and U.F.D

can any one explain   why $10=(3+i)(3-i)=2\times 5$ does not contradict unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Is any way to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is UFD from the definition of UFD

thank you.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2=(1+i)(1-i)$ is not a prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$.  Also $5=(2+i)(2-i)$.  The prime factorization of $10$ is $(1+i)(1-i)(2+i)(2-i)$ and $(1+i)(2-i)=3+i$

Comment: ..thank you sir for your time i understand now...can tell me how to prove $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is UFD  from the definition

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD from the definitions, is to show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has a Euclidean division algorithm, and hence is a PID and a UFD, using the definition of a UFD. I believe that every reasonable proof anyway will use the Euclidean norm $N(x)=x\overline{x}=a^2+b^2$ for $x=a+bi$. So I don't see
a good reason to avoid the standard proof with the division algorithm and the Euclidean norm.